# jstl not parsing in netbeans 8 and tomcat 8

Tags: java, netbeans, java-ee-7, netbeans-8, tomcat8

I have deployed a web application having a sample jstl page in Tomcat 8 using Netbeans 8.

Netbeans is showing red lines in jstl code although I have added jstl jars in the library. Its not able to parse the code.

The web page also shows jstl codes as it is not able to parse the code.

Here are some screenshots -

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make it a .jsp page and try it.

Comment: That works... required quite an eye for noticing that... Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should tell Tomcat which files it needs to process as JavaServerPages. The default is `*.jsp`, so you probably want to rename your file to `index.jsp`. You can however change this configuration in your `web.xml` with the following code:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xyz</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```